# How can I make mobile version of an existing web site?

Tags: java, blackberry, mobile

We have a website coded with jsp-Java. Now, we want to show our website more user friendly on blackberry etc. Is there any tool or method to do this issue more easier?

thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you've written your HTML, you could simply add a mobile-stylesheet to your application. My suggestions for what you would do inside that are make links bigger with padding, so they can be easily selected on touch-screens and generally ensure a long-thin layout (with fluid width to fit any screen size).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="handheld"/>
```